# vue3 and sonarqube, data return say: Not covered by tests

Tags: vue.js, sonarqube, vuejs3, testunit

hy all,
I state that I have already read the other issues on this problem but I have not found what is right for me, or rather: I believe that sonarqube should not manage my code like this, let me explain:

it signals, in almost all returns, that it failed to run the unit test and, for this reason, the entire application is branded as "failed". But the Vue3 data construct, which uses the default return (doesn't seem complicated and abstruse to me) shouldn't be tested? How could I fix it?

Thank you all.[image]